# Не появляется картинка в адаптивном шапке

Tags: html, css

не отображается картинка в адаптивном изображении. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.car{
width:550px;
height:360px;
margin-top:-210px;
margin-left: 70px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:568px) {
.car {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-top:-210px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Высота картинки 100px, а margin-top -210px. Возможно улетает вверх. Попробуй убрать маргин. А лучше кинь кода на play code.io

Comment: margin убрал. Нет изменений.

Comment: Код кинь на playcode.io или сюда (html\css) , а картинки можно взять тут:  http://picsum.photos